# Assigning Value but get null value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I assign the value by getting all value to a variable that is string but when I print value I get null value from that variable. I am using "ids" variable to assign value.

Here is code

```
ids = "";
if ($('input[name=msg_sel]:checked', '#' + tableid).length) {
    $.colorbox({
        initialHeight: '0',
        initialWidth: '0',
        href: "#confirm_dialog",
        inline: true,
        opacity: '0.3',
        onComplete: function () {
            $('.confirm_yes').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('input[name=msg_sel]:checked', oTable.fnGetNodes()).closest('tr').fadeTo(300, 0, function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                    oTable.fnDeleteRow(this);
                    ids += $(this).attr("id").substring(3);
                    //alert(ids); here it  works correct
                    $('.select_msgs', '#' + tableid).attr('checked', false);
                });
                //  here it is shows null value
                alert(ids + "");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: your function runs after the fade has completed. Your alert runs after the fade is triggered. `ids` hasn't been populated at that point.

Comment: Where it shows null, why you concatenate empty string?

Comment: @Dave thanks sir you are right :) thank you versy much

Comment: @Dave,  why ids shows as null, while globally it's instantiated to empty string?

Comment: @stackunderflow not sure; it may be getting set elsewhere since it seems to be a global variable.